# PHP regex numbers in url

Tags: php, regex

I've got a blog, I want to display ADS or special text on the MAIN page but not on any other page with the URI `/?paged=[number]`. I've tried the standard regex `/^[0-9].$/` but it fails to match.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong or how to go about doing this

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/") > 0 AND
substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/?paged=1") == 0 AND
substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/?paged=2") == 0 AND
substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/?paged=3") == 0 AND
substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/?paged=4") == 0 AND
substr_count($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "/?paged=5") == 0) {
echo "display special text, banners, and other stuff";
}
```

This is how I'm doing it currently, but I don't want to do thousands of these...

Comment: Why not just `if(!isset($_GET['paged']))` ?

Comment: When I see code like this I'm reminded of why I don't miss http://thedailywtf.com/ anymore since I became more active on SO.

Comment: If you take a look at your logical comparison **IT HAS NO SENSE**. You are checking if your URI have `"/?paged=1", "/?paged=2", "/?paged=3", "/?paged=4", "/?paged=5"` at the same time and this will **NEVER** match, obviusly. You have to add `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: **IT HAVE NO SENSE**.. Oh the irony.

Comment: btw, /^[0-9].$/ means, a digit, then any character. The dot is a wildcard itself. Perhaps you meant to use + ?

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX check the question again. It wanting show it exclude items with paged= - so its checking it doesnt match 'any' of the terms. So wants to check that none match. So the logic is right, its just not a good way to solve it.

Comment: @barryhunter No, it's not. Even if he don't want that items, you will check if your URI has `/?paged=1` or `/?paged=2`, etc., but you will never get `"/?paged=1/?paged=2...` at your URI. You need to check every `/paged=[number]` separatly and to do so you will need to put `OR` condition instead `AND`

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX `substr_count(...) == 0` returns a false if it finds something, and a true if it does not.  Therefore, he only gets true out of the statement if he does NOT find `/?paged=1` AND does NOT find `/?paged=2` AND does NOT find `/?paged=3` and etcetera and etcetera and etcetera.  You seem to think that if he finds one of the `/?paged=#` items, it'll get him into that if statement, but it's the opposite.  He's testing for NONE of them, not for one or more of them.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe What????????? O.o `substr_count(...)` returns a number. Unless **ALL** `substr_count(...)` returns a number equal to `0` he will never get in the `if` statement. I think it is not hard to understand :S I missed to say something?

Comment: @DaGliMiOuX Yes, it returns a number - the number of times it is found in the string.  If it returns a 0, that means it was found in the string 0 times.  So yes.  He is looking to make sure they ALL return 0.  And they will all return 0 only if none of those strings are in the URI.

Comment: @DaGliMiOuX he WANTS all substr_count to match. Its saying it doesnt have ANY paged= in the URL. (but the first one says does have a slash)

Answer (score 7):

Can you not just check for the presence of `paged` in the `GET` array?

```
if(!isset($_GET['paged'])) {
    // You know this is the main page.
}
```

Comment: Plus one.  And even if you want to make sure it's a valid number - then make sure those valid numbers are stored somewhere so you can check it against a database.  There's no way those should be hardcoded in.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe Agreed. It's often best to port values like that into some persistent structure, so your code is as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('#paged=\d+#', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) {
    echo "display special text, banners, and other stuff";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex:  `/^[0-9].$/` would be correct for "3k" string. Analize this patterns

```
/page=(\d+)/
/page=([1-5])/
/^\/\?page=([1-5])$/
/page=(?<page>[1-5])/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the regexp in the GET parameter ?

```
<?php
$regexp = "/^(\d+)+$";
if (preg_match($regexp, $_GET['paged'])) {
    #...your code
} else {
    #...your code
}
```

Or (if you want to use the entire string) try this:

```
<?php
$regexp = "/^(\/\?paged)+=(\d+)+$/";
```